# How to change colors of address bar (omnibox) in a Chrome theme?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

Chrome recently got an update (at least in Canary) where you can modify Chrome themes and change the background and text colors of the address bar. However, I could not find out the syntax or key words needed to change these colors.

The following is from the manifest.json file of a theme called Just Black. I added `"omnibox_background": [ 65, 65, 65 ]` but it didn't change background color of address bar.

```
{
   "description": "Just Black: when you're feeling extra moody",
   "key": "(long random string of characters)",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Just Black",
   "theme": {
      "colors": {
         "bookmark_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "frame": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_background": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_text": [ 125, 134, 142 ],
         "tab_background_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_inactive": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_incognito": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_incognito_inactive": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "toolbar": [ 45, 45, 45 ],
         "omnibox_background": [ 65, 65, 65 ]
      },
      "tints": {
         "buttons": [ 0.2, 0.2, 0.9 ],
         "frame_inactive": [ -1, -1, -1 ],
         "frame_incognito": [ -1, -1, -1 ],
         "frame_incognito_inactive": [ -1, -1, -1 ]
      }
   },
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2"
}
```

Comment: There's no such setting. You'll have to add `--force-dark-mode` command line switch in Windows.

Comment: @wOxxOm didn't work for me in canary

Comment: Works for me and other people. Make sure you've exited all chrome.exe processes.

Comment: My own custom theme works with that switch so I guess there is a setting that makes the difference: https://puu.sh/EPmwC/89e53d89c5.zip

Comment: @wOxxOm How can I keep accent color on title bar of Explorer but not in Chrome?

Comment: @wOxxOm Are you testing it in Canary?

Comment: @wOxxOm As soon as I imported your theme, the omnibox turned white.

Comment: I don't know then what's happening as it works for me both in Canary and stable.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, maybe some problem at my end. I decided to uninstall Canary lol

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm four months late but you actually can you were on the right track, but if you copy and paste this into the manifest, (highlight the whole manifest), then go to `chrome://extensions`, click `Load unpacked extensions` in the top right, then find the theme file and click select folder then it should work and if it doesn't, contact me by this thread again (edit: you can also change the `"omnibox_background": [65, 65, 65]` and `"omnibox_text": [255, 255, 255]` RGB values to the RGB values of your choosing)

```
{
   "description": "Just Black: when you're feeling extra moody",
   "key": "(long random string of characters)",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Just Black",
   "theme": {
      "colors": {
         "bookmark_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "frame": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_background": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
         "ntp_text": [ 125, 134, 142 ],
         "omnibox_background": [ 65, 65, 65 ],
         "omnibox_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_inactive": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_incognito": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_background_text_incognito_inactive": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "tab_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
         "toolbar": [ 45, 45, 45 ],
      },
      "tints": {
         "buttons": [ 0.2, 0.2, 0.9 ],
         "frame_inactive": [ -1, -1, -1 ],
         "frame_incognito": [ -1, -1, -1 ],
         "frame_incognito_inactive": [ -1, -1, -1 ]
      }
   },
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the Omnibox background when it's expanded during typing something